# Good way to store word counts in database?

Tags: database, word-count, spam-prevention

I'm trying to write a spam filter that learns by sampling a huge amount of spam and not-spam messages, judging by word counts if a message is spam.

I need a good way to add word counts of new messages in a database, so the total count accumulates. For example:

```
# initial database
spam:
  buy: 1
  my: 1
  shit: 1
```

And if I do:

```
spam_filter.learn({:message => "Buy this", :type => :spam})
```

The database will look like:

```
spam:
  buy: 2
  my: 1
  shit: 1
  this: 1
```

Is using YAML a good idea? The point is, of course, that I would like to look up the counts of words of the message I want to analyze later.

I know very little of the nitty gritty theory of databases, but would love to learn more, any recommendation on which technique to use, or a learning resource is welcome.

Comment: If you don't have a lot of data, MySQL should work for you. If you want to learn something about relational databases, "Introduction to Databases" from Coursera might be helpful in giving a good basis, though you will have to invest some time into it.

Comment: That course looks good, I signed up for it. So incrementing counts for a given key should be a trivial task in MySQL?

Comment: afaik yes, as long as that means looking up a row based on the index (in that case, the term) and incrementing a value stored in that row.

Comment: Why the bayesian tag? Nothing in the question mentions Bayes.

Comment: I agree it is unneccessary. In case you didn't know, this kind of approach is called Bayesian text classification.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a database guy, but if all you want to store is this then you might be best just using a hash and saving it as a text file if required. With a database you'll have a bit of an overhead finding and updating the records which may make text just as fast.

There are lots of python tutorials which cover this sort of scenario - what language are you using?

If you really want to use a database, I'd recommend Postgresql or maybe just something inmemory for now. Maybe you could elaborate on why you think a relational db is required - do you have other data to store, is work framework already hooked up to a db. In which case a table of words and another table of word_counts should work fine, but a denormalised db of just word_counts (id, word, count)-> flat file will be faster for search and update.